# COQ definition curry howard (A -> B -> C) -> (B -> A -> C) using sets

Tags: coq, curry-howard

I've been staring this in the face for hours not understanding :(

I need to solve some definitions using coq, and I am supposed to do it via the Curry Howard isomorphism. I have read up and still have no clue what I am doing. I have looked at other examples and tried doing it those ways and I always get errors.

For example, here I need to define this:

```
Variables A B C : Set.

Definition c01 : (A -> B -> C) -> (B -> A -> C) :=
```

this was my attempt:

```
fun g => fun p => g (snd p) (fst p).
end.
```

I also tried

```
fun f => fun b => fun a => f (b , a)
end.
```

Eventually it just says it was expecting a different type than what I gave, and sometimes it says things like: "expected to have type "?9 * ?10"."

Really struggling to grasp this after reading everything I could find.

Please could somebody explain :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you do not know how to read the types correctly.

`c01`'s type is `(A -> B -> C) -> (B -> A -> C)`. That means it is a function, which takes a function as argument and returns a function.

It takes "a function with two arguments" (*I mean in the **Haskell** sense of "a function with two arguments", not in the Scala or Java sense*), of type `A` and `B`, which returns a value of type `C`.

It must return a function with two arguments, of type `A` and `B` (*but in the other order*), which returns a value of type `C`.

So what must this function, `c01`, do?

It must take a function, and turn it into the same function with the order of its arguments reversed.

So:

```
fun f => fun b => fun a => f a b
```

Or equivalently (just adding some parentheses to make it clearer):

```
fun f => (fun b => fun a => f a b)
```